# Check one of the form input fields is not empty in php

Tags: php, forms, post, text, input

Could you please inform how to check one of the form input fields is not empty in php, no matter what input field names are.

```
<form name="form1" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="a">
<input type="text" name="b">
</form>
```

However, please do not inform me the following codes as I know.

```
 if ($_POST["a"] != "" || $_POST["b"] != "")
 { [proceed....] }
```

Answer (score 3):

Loop through the POST array and test the value like this perhaps

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
    foreach( $_POST as $field => $value ){
        if( !empty($value) ){
            exit( $field . 'is NOT empty' );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: $name has first set to the $field before use it in the exit()

Comment: good catch - that should be `$field` rather than `$name` ~ thanks for spotting my deliberate mistook '-)

Comment: What is `$name` here?

Answer (score 0):

The if statement can get quite long if there are multiple input fields.

You should use [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function on POST data.

Try this:

```
 if (array_filter($_POST)) {
    echo "Proceed";
 } else {
    echo "One of the fields is blank";
 }
```